# Can scoreboards detect if a player is killed with a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a sword that will gain attack damage every time a player gets a kill with it. I think I can get the sword attributes to change based on a scoreboard, but I don't know if I can make a scoreboard that detects if a player is killed by someone using the sword. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give yourself an item, for example a sword, include this nbt:
`{customid:"leveling_sword",AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage",Name:"generic.attack_damage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUID:[I;1634486241,408504796,-1808684184,1791120101],Slot:"mainhand"}]}`

It doesn't matter what the UUID is because we will use a custom NBT tag.

Setup commands (run once):
`/scoreboard objectives add kill playerKillCount kill```\

For the looped commands you either put them in this order using 1 repeating and multiple chain command blocks, or just use a function in a datapack.

Looped commands:

```
/execute as @a[scores={kill=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{customid:"leveling_sword"}}] run <modify the SelectedItem>
/scoreboard players set @a kill 0
```

For the  part I'm not sure on the exact stuff to do. I know 2 options but I don't have time rn so imma just post this and someone else might have a better idea.

Option one is to replace the first command with /item:
`item modify @a[scores={kill=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{customid:"leveling_sword"}}] <modifier>` where  points to a json file in a loaded datapack

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_modifier

Option two is to use /data using NBT path format which doesn't require a datapack. However you can't use /data on a player so you first have to move the item to another entity like an armor stand. You might need one armor stand per player in case there are 2 kills on the same game tick. A possibility is to put a marker armor stand on each player's head using /ride.